# QSortFilterProxyModel creates blank items

Tags: python, pyside2, qsortfilterproxymodel, qabstractlistmodel

What I'm trying to do: Take items from a model and sort them using a sorting proxy by a different role:
Expected output:

[image: What I want to happen:]

Real output contains blank lines which shouldn't be there:

[image: You can see the empty lines expand the ListView and can even be selected by cursor]

You can see the empty lines expand the ListView and can even be selected by cursor.

Here's the code that produces this incorrect behaviour:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import string
import random

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +" "+ str(self.value)

class MyCustomModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.list)

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self.list):
            return None

        item = self.list[row]
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(item)
        if role == Qt.UserRole:
            return item.value
        else:
            return None

    def add(self, item):
        rc = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rc, rc+1)
        self.list.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model = MyCustomModel()
        self.listView = QListView(self)

        self.sortingProxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.sortingProxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.sortingProxy.setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)
        self.sortingProxy.sort(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)

        self.listView.setModel(self.sortingProxy)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

        # create some random data for the model
        for i in range(10):
            randomName = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(8)])
            self.model.add(MyItem(randomName, random.randint(0, 30)))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
app.exec_()
```

I've tracked down the issue to QSortFilterProxyModel because when it's removed the problem goes away, but the program no longer sorts the data:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import string
import random

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +" "+ str(self.value)

class MyCustomModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.list)

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self.list):
            return None

        item = self.list[row]
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(item)
        if role == Qt.UserRole:
            return item.value
        else:
            return None

    def add(self, item):
        rc = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rc, rc+1)
        self.list.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model = MyCustomModel()
        self.listView = QListView(self)

        self.listView.setModel(self.model)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

        # create some random data for the model
        for i in range(10):
            randomName = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(8)])
            self.model.add(MyItem(randomName, random.randint(0, 30)))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
app.exec_()
```

Because the problem seems to be caused by Pyside2/Qt5 code it seems I have no idea how to counter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the proxy, the problem is caused by the method you use to add items, if you review the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) you must pass the row number from and to where it is added, in this case as only 1 is added then both match , in the general case if n-elements are added, the solution is:

```
rc = self.rowCount()
self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rc, rc + n - 1)
```

So in your case the solution is:

```
def add(self, item):
    rc = self.rowCount()
    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rc, rc)
    self.list.append(item)
    self.endInsertRows()
```

Comment: Yes! Fixed the problem, many thanks. I wonder why the problem never appeared without the sorting proxy though. Regardless, thank you.